# How to pass CromeOptions via MVN command line

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Goal : 
To pass `options.addArguments("--headless");` in the command line.

What's in mind : 
`mvn clean test --Chrome.options.AddArguments("--headless)` ?

getDriver method:

```
        try {
            java.util.Properties p = new Properties();
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + "/src/main/resources/config.properties");
            p.load(fi);
            String browserName = p.getProperty("default.browser");
            switch (browserName) {
                case "chrome" :
                    setChromeDriverPath();
                    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.addArguments("test-type");
                    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
                    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                    //options.addArguments("--kiosk");
                    //options.addArguments("--headless");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                    break;
                case "firefox" :
                    System.out.println("BROWSER DRIVER - FIREFOX - NOT IMPLEMENTED YET");
                    break;
                case "safari" :
                    System.out.println("BROWSER DRIVER - SAFARI - NOT IMPLEMENTED YET");
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load browser : getDriver returns : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will have to work with the concept of the property function through the System. In general, you will need to create some variables like browser, version, headless or not, etc. and you will make them readable as properties inside your code sample. Every time you will execute your mvn command, you will include after the command the option you want by writing `-Dbrowser="Chrome"`, for example. After that, your code will need to handle the value "Chrome" accordingly. For more details check this link [here](https://eltestor.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/pass-parameters-from-command-line-to-a-selenium-project-using-maven-command/).

It's a really good analysis. It will solve your problem.